# C++ - How can I link the OpenSSL library in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, openssl, linker

I'm trying to link [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks). I've moved the files to "include" directory and also I have changed the name of "configuration.h.in" to "configuration.h", but now I receive these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in lokk (compiler: Cywin) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|27|error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|27|error: stray '@' in program|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|28|error: stray '@' in program|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|34|error: stray '@' in program|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|38|error: stray '@' in program|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|39|error: stray '@' in program|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|49|error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|55|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|57|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|58|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\configuration.h|59|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|104|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|112|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|116|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|120|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|139|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|149|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|159|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|169|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|179|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|189|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\macros.h|199|error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stddef.h|24|error: expected ',' or ';' before 'extern'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevCpp\MinGW64\include\openssl\types.h|20|fatal error: openssl/safestack.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 24 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you simply dumped files from the OpenSSL source distribution into your header include paths ( NEVER add or change files there). You are instead supposed to compile and install OpenSSL.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the Conan package manager instead to build and install OpenSSL for you. If you still want to try, you can find instructions on how to do it yourself here: [How to compile OpenSSL on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007633/how-to-compile-openssl-on-windows) It is not for the faint of heart and not especially educational.

Comment: Re *"Cywin"*? Not *"[Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?